# what is the difference between display hidden and display none in css3?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what's the difference between display none and display hidden in CSS?
when are both of them used and in which context?

I want to create an division which remains hidden until i click a button on the homepage.

Comment: Is there a `display: hidden`? https://nimb.ws/PAgHSz

Comment: Do you mean `visibility: hidden;`?  There is no `display: hidden;`...

Comment: This is the sort of question where it's worth looking at a reliable source - e.g. search for 'MDN CSS hidden' etc. MDN not only gives an explanation it also gives example code.

Answer (score 2):

visibility hidden hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout. display none removes the element from the document. It does not take up any space.